# Image on HTML disappears after adding external jQuery link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image

My javascript is currently blank but I added in the external link to my javascript (`<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js">`) into the header of my HTML to begin. However, my image disappears completely.

HTML:

```
<HTML>

<HEAD>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js">

</HEAD>


<BODY>

<div id="hong">
    <img id="hong" src="images/hong.png">
</div>

</BODY>


</HTML>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: are you positive about the path of the file?

Comment: close your script tag like `<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is you have not closed the script tag, `script` is not a self closing tag(tested the behavior in chrome)

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the correct path of the image.

Answer (score 0):

Close your script tag

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
```

not

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js">
```

Script tags are strange that way. They're more like  tags than  tags, in that you have to open then and close them. Even if content between the script tags is optional.